# parse key:value pairs in SQL postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have a string that contains a semicolon separated list of key value pairs.

E.g ref:12345;code:ab  etc.

I would like to split it into 'ab' as code,'241376' as ref,etc.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of regexp_split_to_table and split_part.

Have a look at [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-string.html).

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (myText text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ref:12345;code:ab;ref:5678;code:cd');

SELECT
    split_part(pair, ':', 1) as name,
    split_part(pair, ':', 2) as value
FROM
    (SELECT regexp_split_to_table(myText, ';') pair FROM t) t1
```

Result:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| ref | 12345 |
| code | ab |
| ref | 5678 |
| code | cd |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=46ff5479f9e379d9b14302f20faea2a1)*

**UPDATE**

According to your comment if your desired result is:

xxx as code
xxx as ref

You can use:

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT(split_part(pair, ':', 2), ' as ', split_part(pair, ':', 1)) RESULT
FROM (SELECT regexp_split_to_table(myText, ';') pair FROM t) t1
```

That returns:

| result |
| --- |
| 12345 as ref |
| ab as code |
| 5678 as ref |
| cd as code |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=5c562b8ead7533f9c06263c51642effa)*

Comment: thanks how to split it into '12345' as ref,'ab' as code,etc.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit messy but I hope self explanatory.

```sql
with t as 
(
  select (r + 1)/2 as r, 
    split_part(txt, ':', 1) as k, 
    split_part(txt, ':', 2) as v
  from unnest(string_to_array('ref:12345;code:ab;ref:5678;code:cd;ref:9876;code:yz', ';'))
  with ordinality as t(txt, r)
)
select
    max(v) filter (where k = 'ref') as ref_fld,
    max(v) filter (where k = 'code') as code_fld
from t group by r;
```

Result:

| ref_fld | code_fld |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | ab |
| 9876 | yz |
| 5678 | cd |